# How to re-order pinned entries in Windows 10 JumpList

Tags: windows-10, jumplist, ordering

I have some pinned entries in the Jumplists for various of my Taskbar-pinned programs:

[image]

I want to re-order those pinned entries. **Is there any way to do so?**

Drag-and-droping does nothing, alas.

Comment: Not sure if this program will do what you need>>>>>>https://www.nirmaltv.com/2010/09/27/create-a-jumplist-of-favorite-programs-in-windows-7-with-seven-jump/

Comment: To reorder pinned items you unpin them and re pin them.

Answer (score 8):

Jump lists are created automatically when a user interacts with the system, doing such acts as opening applications or accessing files,
are stored in the folder:

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\
```

They all have cryptic names based on the application id (APPID).
For example, the one for Explorer is
`f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms`.

An `automaticDestinations-ms` file is a Structured Storage file and cannot
easily be read in Notepad or the like.
You may use for that the
[Jump List View utility](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/jump_lists_view.html)
from NirSoft, where the "Application ID" column contains the APPID.
This app fails to give the name of the application itself, but you may infer it from
the item's file-path.

The files themselves are in
[COM Structured Storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/structured-storage-start-page)
format that is hard to read and even harder to update.

The entries can be read and modified by a utility such as
[Structured Storage Viewer](http://mitec.cz/ssv.html),
but they are displayed in hex, so this is not an easy task.
There also exist libraries for programs needing to access these files.

For more information, read the article
[Windows 10 Jump List Forensics](https://www.blackbagtech.com/blog/windows-10-jump-list-forensics/).

A utility that can do more is the
[Jump List Manager](http://www.download-utility.com/Jump-List-Manager-Software-Windows-7.htm),
whose usage is also explained in this
[tutorial](https://www.technorms.com/5119/windows-7-jumplists-manager).
It was conceived for Windows 7, but still works in Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Downvote : please explain.

Comment: I did not downvote, but my guess would be that it's because there's no explicit answer to the direct question? You've provided a whole bunch of really valuable contextual information ... but the answer to the question is implicit, not explicit. I've proposed an edit to resolve that (hopefully my edit accurate represents your answer. If it doesn't then it kinda proves my point that the direct answer isn't obvious :) )

Comment: Apparently your edit was rejected by other users, not me. However, I added another utility that fully answers your question. I even tested it and it works.

Comment: That looks GREAT! Thank you so much. I'll give it a test, and then come back and accept your answer (assuming that tool does what it says it does)

Comment: I'm not the down voter either, but my assumption is you have some disgruntled workers lurking in the shadows or something strange and odd like that!

Comment: @harrymc, I forgot to ever come back to update. I don't understand why JLM was made, because (having no downloaded it) it only lets you edit ***it's own** jump list!? So alas it doesn't help. I've reached out to the developers to see if I can get the source code, and perhaps massage it into something more useful for my needs :D

Comment: I tested it when I wrote my answer and it worked well. Perhaps some Windows update caused a problem.

Comment: Currently the link to the download for the JLM is broken and the JLM site seems to be offline.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the order of the items in the jump lists of taskbar. But there is a workaround to do so. First unpin all items from the jump list. Then pin all items again in your order. I know, this process is a bit lengthy and time consuming, but i can't find any other way.

Comment: I believe this is the best answer. For pinned items (which OP specifies) simply repinning these in the order you wish is the best way.

Comment: Thank you @music2myear!

Comment: Hi @PimpJuiceIT, i edited the answer with a bit more information. Sorry, but i can't find anything new. (Also i am not a new user, i am leaving my older account for some private reasons)